# Htaccess Rewrite Rule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm getting crazy with .htaccess and rewrite rule.
I'd like to understand how it works, I hate it, anyway here's my problem.

(really simple for most of you)

My site has one main page `index.php`.
This is the only page, all the others are handled by this one.

I did a simple `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?page=$1
```

to do this:

```
/index.php?page=VAL -> /VAL
```

But I don't know how create a rule for this:

```
/index.php?page=VAL&var1=VAL2&var2=VAL3 etc.
```

I'd like a final URL like:

```
/VAL/VAL2/VAL3 etc.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just rewrite the request to your *index.php* and parse the requested URI path with PHP:

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI_PATH'] = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
$segments = implode('/', ltrim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI_PATH'], '/'));
```

And the rule to that:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule !^index\.php$ index.php [L]
```

This will rewrite every request, that’s URI path can not be mapped to an existing file, to your *index.php*.

Comment: ok, if I understood well, the RewriteCond checks if the uripath isn't a file, but can you explain me what RewriteRule does? thanks

Comment: @Marcx: The `RewriteRule` will rewrite any request, that’s URI path (without path prefix) is not `index.php`, to `index.php`.

Comment: ah thank you.. so `!` not `index.php` (path prefix) will be rewrite to `index.php` ok thank you so much..

Comment: @Marcx: Oh yes, `!` at the begin negates the expression. So the rule is applied if `^index\.php$` does not match.