# htaccess rewrite rule for affiliate id

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My site is just index.php and every page is read from that. I'm not using WordPress.

What I'm seeking to do is the same thing that WordPress does with its page structure. In Wordpress you can set the rewrite rule so that a subsequent subdirectory can pass a value to `index.php`.

I have a client that is building an affiliate network and the base URL is for example:

```
mywebsite.com/?id=viktor
```

They would like to parse URL's instead so that it's much simpler for the customers.

i.e. `mywebsite.com/u/viktor` would 'rewrite' to `mywebsite.com/?id=viktor`.

What would be the `.htaccess` rule or associated PHP I'd have to put in `index.php`?

Obviously we won't have a 'u' folder in the site. :)

Thanks for your help.

[This related question I believe has the code we're looking for however I'm not sure how it would apply in this situation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435833/htaccess-rewrite-rule)

Comment: What format is the affiliate ID? Should the rewrite always take the user back to the `mywebsite.com` homepage, or the page they requested by passing in the URL param?

Comment: It is a username such as id=viktor however we do not want it to redirect. When bookmarked it still shows up as mywebsite.com/u/viktor and passes the id variable to index.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^u/(.+)$ /?id=$1 [NE,L]
```

If you need to also preserve any existing query string (like `/u/viktor?param=value`), use this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^u/(.+)$ /?id=$1 [NE,QSA,L]
```

**Update**

Well it's bad practice using relative URLs (for this reason), but if you really want to avoid updating all your code, which could easily be done with a script or a command, you could do this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^u/(.+/.+) /$1 [NE,L]
RewriteRule ^u/(.+)$ /?id=$1 [NE,QSA,L]
```

Which would rewrite everything that is referenced in a folder under `/u/` to root. But it breaks browser caching as all your resources now have two URLs. Really you should just update your URLs to absolute.

If the above doesn't work for you and you only want to rewrite specific folders, do it like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^u/((?:assets|images|css)/.+) /$1 [NE,L]
RewriteRule ^u/(.+)$ /?id=$1 [NE,QSA,L]
```

Replacing your folder names as appropriate.

Comment: This worked however UNIX still sees the CSS i.e.  href="assets/css/custom-animations.css" as inside of a 'u' folder so the images aren't asbolutely referenced.   We'd have to go in and redo every line of code, ever include and add a / to it.  Is there a way to rewrite the rule but still move the 'directory' back to the root even though we put the /u/  - see http://ufunnel.net/u/earthgrid - you can see the CSS and everything isn't loading because it thinks its in the 'u' folder. We're close!!!!!

Comment: Is there an easier way than modifying all the relative references of every file and page to absolutes?

such as - when you rewrite - also drop back a directory i.e.  ../  for all references.  It's a mind bender!  Thanks for your help!

Comment: I added an update about that. It's not UNIX that sees it that way, it's the web browser.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have here, Viktor, is that WordPress checks the *original* URL when it is processing a request. This is because it has its own mod_rewrite rules to rewrite everything to `index.php`.

So you can't do what you want with `mod_rewrite`, because WordPress won't look at your rewritten URL, and will process it as `/u/viktor`. You can do it with a 301 redirect, but you already said you don't want to do that.

In order to make this work properly, you need to work with WordPress to make those URLs work, perhaps creating a plug-in to do it. I wouldn't suggest adding anything to WordPress's `index.php` as it will only get overwritten when WordPress is updated.

Comment: The OP isn't using Wordpress, they just want to do some things that Wordpress is using.

Comment: So I see now the question has been updated :) Thanks for the heads up.